# Problem with borders when converting huxtable into flextable

Tags: r, flextable, huxtable

I want to convert a huxtable into a flextable and for this I use huxtable::as_flextable. Know I need to set some borders (also completely on the right and on the left). Everything works fine but there is no border completely on the right in the first row. I really don't know why. Is there a bug in huxtable or flextable? And how could I fix that?

My code:

```
hux(
  c("", "X"),
  c("", "Y"),
  c("", "Z"),
  c("A", "1"),
  c("", "2"),
  c("B", "1"),
  c("", "2"),
  c("C", "1"),
  c("", "2")
) %>% 
  merge_cells(1, 1:3) %>% 
  merge_cells(1, 4:5) %>% 
  merge_cells(1, 6:7) %>%
  merge_cells(1, 8:9) %>% 
  set_top_border(value = 0.5) %>% 
  set_left_border(row = 1:2, col = 1, value = 0.5) %>% 
  set_right_border(row = 1:2, col = c(3, 5, 7, 9), value = 0.5) %>% 
  huxtable::as_flextable()
```

That's the result:

[image: My result]

Comment: This looks like a bug in huxtable - assuming you have the latest version. You might try setting right border on row 1 and column 8. The merge seems to be messing things up.

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer, this really solves the problem! Thank you very much! You can add an answer, I will accept it (soon!)

Comment: This bug should now be fixed in the github development version.